# How is PAM-3 used with binary digits?

Tags: digital-modulation

I've seen [a post on Anandtech.](https://www.anandtech.com/show/16858/intel-executive-posts-thunderbolt-5-photo-80-gbps-and-pam3-then-deletes-it)  Apparently Intel is planning to use PAM-3 for USB80.

My question, how efficiently can we map binary digits into a PAM-3 modulation?

For instance, 2 successive PAM-3 "digits" have 9 possible values (00, 01, 02... 22)

My naïve implementation would be to map 3 bits into 2 PAM-3 digits, we use 8 values out of 9, meaning the mapping efficiency is 88.888%. Is there a way to get closer to 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can code more bits at a time.

3 bits => 2 trits is a ratio of 1.5.

11 bits => 7 trits is a ratio of 1.572.

19 bits => 12 trits is a ratio of 1.583.

The best you could possibly get is log(3) / log(2) which is slightly less than 1.585. Which means that even using the 3 => 2 mapping is 94.6% efficient when calculated from a bandwidth perspective instead of a "how much of the code space do we use" perspective; the 19 => 12 mapping is 99.9% efficient. Of course, there's some waste if your frame isn't a multiple of 19 bits long :)

Comment: Though I suppose that with entropy-like coding we might be able to get closer to 100% if we accept some assumptions about the data?

Comment: @Ben yes. I'm making a uniform assumption, which is pretty fair for something general purpose :)

Comment: What’s more important is the cost,complexity of encoding more serial trits and the dispersion of BW, equalization , forward error correction gain in BER and equivalent loss in SNR.